# Array indexing in a for loop on MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

So I understand how to write a very basic for loop running through an array in matlab. The online help example is something as follows

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
for i = 1:numel(A)
  B(i) = A(i).^2
end
```

So this will iterate through each number in the array and square it. And I understand this, But what if I wish to work with previous i values?

My problem is as follows, I wish to make a loop that will perform a Lagrange interpolating polynomial on a matrix of data. Which means I need to work with the i term, the i-1, the i+1 term, etc. What I have is this.

```
A = [1 0.6767; 1.5 0.3734; 1.6 0.3261; 2.5 0.08422; 3.5 0.01596]
    for i = 1:numel(A)
        F_1 = A(i,i+1)*(2*A(i+1,i) - A(i+1,i) - A(i+2,i))/((A(i,i) - A(i+1,i))*(A(i,i) - A(i+1,i)))
              + A(i+1,i+1)*(2*A(i+1,i) - A(i,i) - A(i+2,i))/((A(i+1,i) - A(i,i))*(A(i+1,i) - A(i+2,i)))
              + A(i+2,i+1)*(2*A(i+1,i) - A(i,i) - A(i+1,i))/((A(i+2,i) - A(i,i))*(A(i+2,i) - A(i+1,i)))
    end
```

This obviously isnt working because my programming skills are elementary. How should I be indexing and working with the i term, the i+1 term, etc?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Before we go into indexing term `i+1`: `numel(A)` is the total number of elements in `A`. Your example `A` is a 5x2 matrix, so `numel(A)==10`. In you loop, `i` will obtain values 1 through 10. What do you expect `A(i,i)` to yield? The last element is `A(5,2)`, but you are looking for element `A(10,10)`...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it actually made me mostly get it. Here is what I concluded works (almost) 

A = [1 0.6767; 1.5 0.3734; 1.6 0.3261; 2.5 0.08422; 3.5 0.01596]
 
for i = 2:(size(A,1)-1)
    F_1(i) = A(i-1,2)*(2*A(i,1) - A(i,1) - A(i+1,1))/((A(i-1,1) - A(i,1))*(A(i-1,1) - A(i+1,1)))...
          + A(i,2)*(2*A(i,1) - A(i-1,1) - A(i+1,1))/((A(i,1) - A(i-1,1))*(A(i,1) - A(i+1,1)))...
          + A(i+1,2)*(2*A(i,1) - A(i-1,1) - A(i,1))/((A(i+1,1) - A(i-1,1))*(A(i+1,1) - A(i,1)))
end     %%%only problem is it repeats the first answer twice?

Comment: Please [edit] your post, it’s hard to read code in a comment...